# Button images disappear when screen pixels are less than 960

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify.js

This is my container

```
 <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" xs="6" class="py-2">
        <v-btn-toggle borderless>
          <v-btn value="left">
            <span class="hidden-sm-and-down"><img src="/storage/img/btn-lang/en.png" style="width: 40px" /></span>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn value="center">
            <span class="hidden-sm-and-down"><img src="/storage/img/btn-lang/pt.png" style="width: 40px" /></span>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn value="right">
            <span class="hidden-sm-and-down"><img src="/storage/img/btn-lang/es.png" style="width: 40px" /></span>
          </v-btn>
        </v-btn-toggle>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

but when the screen pixels are less than 960 the images on the buttons disappear

sample images below

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK2s2.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU0QC.png)

Comment: And what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Check the [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/) to see what `class="hidden-sm-and-down"` does.

Comment: @Aleksandar 
that the images do not disappear

Answer (score 0):

the error was due to a class

hidden-sm-and-down

Check the vuetify docs